# alternate of spsolve and spdiag in matlab/octave

Tags: python, matlab, scikit-learn, octave

I have a python code which I am trying to convert to Matlab code. The code is for baseline correction for a wave.

```
def baseline_als(y, lam, p, niter=20):
    L = len(y)
    D = sparse.csc_matrix(np.diff(np.eye(L), 2))
    w = np.ones(L)
    for i in xrange(niter):
        W = sparse.spdiags(w, 0, L, L)
        Z = W + lam * D.dot(D.transpose())
        z = spsolve(Z, w*y)
        w = p * (y > z) + (1-p) * (y < z)
    return z
```

I have tried it converting like this.

```
function [z] = baseline_als(y, lam, p, niter=20)
    L = len(y)
    D = sparse.csc_matrix(diff(eye(L), 2))
    w = ones(L)
    for i = 1:niter
        W = sparse.spdiags(w, 0, L, L) %Not working
        Z = W + lam * dot(D,transpose(D))
        z = spsolve(Z, w*y) % Not working
        w = p * (y > z) + (1-p) * (y < z)
    end % End of For loop
end % End of function
```

However there are no functions named `spsolve` and `spdiag` in octave/matlab. Is there any alternate function that I can use?

Comment: side note: there are no `spdiag` functions in MATLAB/OCTAVE nor in Python. Its `spidiags`, and yes, the MATLAB function has exactly the same syntax as the python one.

Comment: Also note that `D = sparse.csc_matrix(diff(eye(L), 2))` this is not MATLAB syntax, and that you may want to end almost all lines with a semicolon to supress command line output. Also, you can not define default values to the inputs as you did. Your function needs **a lot** of work to be MATLAB

Comment: what can be the alternate of `sparse.csc_matrix()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its quite easy *if you know what spsolve does*.  Lets focus on that, [as `spidiag` seems easier to solve](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html), doesn't it?

`spsolve` "Solve the sparse linear system Ax=b, where b may be a vector or a matrix."

This is exactly what MATLABs`\` or `mldivide` does, it solves a system of Ax=b, for x. Happily for you, MATLAB can deal with both sparse and dense matrix with the same function, thus the change shoudl be as easy as:

from:

```
z = spsolve(Z, w*y)
```

to:

```
z= Z\(w*y);
```